# Client Database

Tags: custom-fields

It looks like this system has all the functions I need for Donor Management and Fundraising.  Does the system also have the capability to house Client Data.  For example, we work with families. For each family, I need to be able to document the following pieces for reporting purposes:

- Family Name (last name, first initial)
- Address
- Phone
- Email
- Number of family members
- Ages of all family members, dividing out between adults and children
- Race of all family members
- Gender of all family members, dividing out between adults and children
- Pre-Assessment Scores (3 different assessments)
- Post-Assessment Scores (3 different assessments)

Is this possible for this system?

---

Answer (score 4):

Based on the limited information in your question, the answer is Yes, Civi can do all of that. There are "Household" contacts as well as Individuals and you can establish relationships between households and individuals.

For your assessments, you can create custom fields you can create to handle pretty much anything you need.

It sounds like your organization might also benefit from the CiviCase module, so be sure to check that out.

You might want to hire a Civi professional to help you formally evaluate if Civi is right for you and, if so, to get it set up.

One of the best assets that Civi has going for it is this helpful and friendly community.

Comment: Endorse what Phil said. There are others using civi in similar fashion if you want to talk with end users rather than the 'providers' about what it can do. Just a note that "Number of family members" could be read in a couple of ways eg let me see all the contacts related to Household/Family X, or 'give me an integer on the Household/Family record that does a count of all related individuals'. The latter is not 'out of the box' but an extension called Summary Fields could be adapted to provide that without too much effort I expect